# How can I get a value of that object from within an object? javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I tried using it like this:

```js
const obj = {
  key1: "value",
  key2: obj.key1
}
```

but give `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'flags' before initialization` error.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Comment: Duplicate of [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Comment: Oh. Thank you! I'm trying.